# XML Data Injection in the response XML from web service

Tags: java, xml, owasp, esapi

I need to fix the code below for XML Data Injection.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlFromWebService));
Document doc = db.parse(inStream);   // reported at this line by a code audit tool
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

How to fix it? Do anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: ya I got you concern. And also after finding and implementing the solution in my module and testing them I have posted the correct solutions to each of the questions asked. I was not known to it.

Comment: hey can u give the solution to this one now!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this has to do with validation of your XML against a given XSD to prevent XML Data Injection. I would suggest modifying your code like this:

```
try {
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  factory.setNamespaceAware( true);
  factory.setValidating( true);

  factory.setProperty( "http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", 
                       "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
  factory.setProperty( "http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", 
                       "file:<your_xsd_file>");

  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
  inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlFromWebService));
  Document document = builder.parse(inStream);

} catch ( ParserConfigurationException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch ( SAXException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch ( IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope you get the hint!

Comment: ya I got the point.have also done some r&d on the same. can u please tell me that what property this setProperty is setting? I am getting setAttribute as the actual name. will it work the same way? Also what should be the value for these properties? Also how all the stuff is going to get the work done by documentBuilderFactory?

Comment: @R.K.R: 1. SchemaLanguage & Schema Source (that's why I kept the second property's value intentionally as <your_xsd_file>).  2. setAttribute would also work. Read these two lines in my code and yoou can understand what to use for the value. 3. I didn't quite understand what did you mean by the last part of your question.

Comment: I mean how documentBuilderfactory is going to validate all the stuff xml? any way I am done with it found all the solutions to the questions and also implemented a demo solution and going get it approved by the client. thanks a lot!!!!!!1

Comment: you're welcome! glad to help. Oh and just in case you found the solution that I proposed acceptable, you might want to accept it :)

Comment: There's no `DocumentBuilderFactory.setProperty()` method. Only `setAttribute()` and `setFeature()`